# Show that any map $f: S^{a + b} \to S^a \times S^b$ induces a zero map on the homology $H_{a + b}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Show that any map $f: S^{a + b} \to S^a \times S^b$ induces a zero map on the homology $H_{a + b}$.

I'm trying to prove this statement. My thought is that: 
Showing this is equivalent to showing that $f$ induces a zero map on the $H^{a+b}$ by the duality theorems in Hatcher (see Proposition 3.34 and remarks around) (is this claim correct?) 
Notice that composing with the projection map on $S^a$, we have
$$ f: S^{a + b} \to S^{a} \times S^b \to S^a$$
which shows that the generator of $H^{a + b}(S^{a + b})$ is the pullback of the generator of $H^{a + b}(S^{a})$, which is zero. 
Hence the result, but I'm not sure if I can use the duality theorem in this way.

Any help or comments are welcomed!!

Comment: I didn't quite understand the last argument about the pullback. However, I would complete by saying that the generators of $H^a(S^a\times S^b)$ and of $H^b(S^a\times S^b)$ both map to zero in $H^*(S^{a+b})$, hence so does their cup-product, which generates $H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem.

*One is to use the naturality of the Hurewicz homomorphism*. This assumes known the standard calculation $H_nS^n\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and that $\pi_{n+k}S^n$ is torsion for $k\geq 1$. Choose, for each $n$, generators $s_n\in H_nS^n\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and for a space $X$ define the *Hurewicz homorphism* $h_n^X:\pi_nX\rightarrow H_nX$ by $h^X_n(\alpha)=\alpha_*s_n$, where $\alpha:S^n\rightarrow X$  represents a homotopy class in $\pi_nX$ and $\alpha_*:H_nS^n\rightarrow H_nX$ is the induced map on homology. For each space $X$ the maps $h^X_n$ are indeed group homomorphisms, as one should check.

Now observe that for a based map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ we have

$$f_*(h_n^X(\alpha))=f_*\alpha_*s_n=(f\circ\alpha)_*s_n=h^Y_n(f_*\alpha)$$

and also that $h^{S^n}_n:\pi_nS^n\rightarrow H_nS^n$ is surjective, since $h^{S^n}_n(id_{S^n})=s_n$.

Turning to the case at hand, let $f:S^{a+b}\rightarrow S^a\times S^b$ be a map, which we may assume without loss of generality to be basepoint preserving. We find that

$$f_*s_n=f_*h^{S^{a+b}}_{a+b}(id_{S^{a+b}})=h^{S^a\times S^b}_n(f_*id_{S^{a+b}})=h^{S^a\times S^b}_n(f).$$

This element must be zero for the following reason: we know that $H_n(S^a\times S^b)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion free, and also that $\pi_{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)\cong\pi_{a+b}(S^a)\oplus\pi_{a+b}(S^b)$ is torsion. Hence $f_*s_n$ lies in the image of the homomorphism $h_{a+b}^{S^a\times S^b}:\pi_{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)\rightarrow H_n(S^a\times S^b)$, which has torsion domain and free codomain so must be the trivial homomorphism. This proves the claim.

*Another approach is through duality*, as you describe. We will need to assume known the cup product structures on $H^*S^{a+b}$ and $H^*(S^a\times S^b)$. We know $H_nS^n\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_{n-1}S^n=0$. Hence $H^nS^n\cong Hom(H_nS^n,\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the pairing $\langle-,-\rangle: H^nS^n\otimes H_nS^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $\langle\alpha,s\rangle s=\alpha(s)$ is non-singular

Thus given $f:S^{a+b}\rightarrow S^a\times S^b$ we have that for $\alpha\in H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)$ and $s\in H_{a+b}S^{a+b}$

$$\langle\alpha,f_*s\rangle=\langle f^*\alpha,s\rangle.$$

We conlcude by non-singularity that $f_*s=0$ if and only if $f^*\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha\in H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)$. That is, $f_*=0$ if and only if $f^*:H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)\rightarrow H^{a+b}S^{a+b}$ is the zero homomorphism.

Now it is not correct that the generator of $H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)$ is the pullback of the generator of $H^{a+b}(S^a)$, since the latter group is trivial. However, as was pointed out in the comments, we can apply the Kunneth theorem and conclude that for generators $s_a\in H^aS^a$ and $s_b\in H^bS^b$ we have that $pr_a^*s_a=s_a\times 1$ generates $H^a(S^a\times S^b)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, that $pr_b^*s_b=1\times s_b$ generates $H^b(S^a\times S^b)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and that $pr_a^*s_a\cup pr_b^*s_b=s_a\times s_b$ generates $H^{a+b}(S^a\times S^b)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

It follows from all this that

$$f^*(pr_a^*s_a\cup pr_b^*s_b)=f^*(pr_a^*s_a)\cup f^*(pr_b^*s_b)=0$$

since there all cup products in $H^*S^{a+b}$ are trivial. We conclude that $f^*=0$ and get the result.